# Making an ajax call and loading the string return by that call into a label in emberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am new to EmberJs. I want to make an ajax call which returns a string. And once I get the data from the ajax call, I want to load the data into a label. Where can I find a simple example for same.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use Ember?

Comment: @SharpCoder The scenario you are presenting doesn't really require Ember. If you can be a little more specific about what you're really trying to achieve, it would be helpful. But keep in mind there's a ton of documentation/screencasts/tutorials focusing on Ember these days. Depending on what you wanna do, you could easily find online resources: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qYtXAfxr-U ... again.. if you could rephrase your question...

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: Thank you for the help. I have started working on this app which uses ember and I need to now add an label which on page load gets some data from server and loads it. Yes, I can just add an input type label, make an ajax call using jquery and then bind the data. But I want to do it ember way

Comment: @torazaburo: The app on which I am working on is making use of ember. I am new to this framework and want to add label. I want to do things ember way :)

Comment: Run through a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple version of what you're asking:

```js
//js 
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {

    Em.run.later(function() {
      $.getJSON('http://baconipsum.com/api/?callback=?', {
          'type': 'meat-and-filler',
          'start-with-lorem': '1',
          'paras': '3'
        },
        function(baconGoodness) {
          if (baconGoodness && baconGoodness.length > 0) {
            $("#bacon").html('');
            for (var i = 0; i < baconGoodness.length; i++)
              $("#bacon").append('<p>' + baconGoodness[i] + '</p>');
            $("#bacon").show();
          }
        });
    }, 800)

  }
});
```

```css
/*css*/
html,
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.6.1/ember.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div id="bacon">Loading bacon...</div>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

As I have no clue what your application looks like, I'll just assume you have a view somewhere in your app that has a template with an html element with an id. If this is not your scenario.. that's fine, use the idea presented here and try to apply in your project.

For this sample, I created an index view with the following template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div id="bacon">Loading bacon...</div> 
</script>
```

It only has a div called `#bacon` which I'm putting the response from some ajax request into.

Then in the `IndexView` class I added a handler for [`didInsertElement`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement) with an ajax request. This means that right after the Index view gets inserted into the DOM, it will fire this request.

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {

    Em.run.later(function() {
      $.getJSON('http://baconipsum.com/api/?callback=?', { 
          'type':'meat-and-filler', 
          'start-with-lorem':'1', 
          'paras':'3' 
      }, 
      function(baconGoodness) {
          if (baconGoodness && baconGoodness.length > 0) {
              $("#bacon").html('');
              for (var i = 0; i < baconGoodness.length; i++) { 
                  $("#bacon").append('<p>' + baconGoodness[i] + '</p>');
              }
              $("#bacon").show();
          }
      });
    }, 800);
  }
});
```

Another approach would be through the `Route`. You could have that ajax request in the [`model`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) hook of your route, and then you can simply use handlebars expressions in your template. Something like this:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {

    return $.getJSON('http://baconipsum.com/api/?callback=?', {
      'type': 'meat-and-filler',
      'start-with-lorem': '1',
      'paras': '3'
    });

  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.6.1/ember.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div>{{model}}</div>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

That `div` doesn't need an `id` anymore, since we are using the controller's `model` property in the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div>{{model}}</div> 
</script>
```

Then the route implementation goes like this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {

    return $.getJSON(
        'http://baconipsum.com/api/?callback=?', {
            'type':'meat-and-filler', 
            'start-with-lorem':'1', 
            'paras':'3' 
        });
    }
});
```

If this code doesn't apply to your scenario, try explaining it a little better. It really depends on what you are doing. Please follow the tutorials, read blogs, watch screen cats... keep your self up to date (not just ember).

This could have been done differently.. in many ways.. so it really depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Though I wanted to use second approach, for some reason its not working. I have used the first approach which is working. But I wanted to ember model for this.

Comment: Why cant I use ember model in the first approach ?? Instead of `$("#bacon").html('').apped(result);` I want to assign this value to model.

Comment: All I can say is for you to learn MVC. Learn it well. Then learn well Ember flavored MVC. Then you'll understand more, especially why things aren't working the way you want. And sometimes you'll see that the way you want isn't really the way it should be. For this particular case, while you're loading the route, your view layer isn't available as it hasn't rendered yet. If you really want to do this in the model, then you wont have the `loading` thing, but you'll still have a dynamic label of sorts. Spend some time learning it well. It's an investment you make on yourself.